# Как считать текст из скомпилированого файла? C#

Tags: c#, текст

Здравствуйте.
У меня такая проблема:
есть файл (не знаю как скомпилированный), но в нем есть одна текстовая (которую можно нормально прочитать) строка. Я программно ее вырезал и записал в переменную **text**.
Потом она записывается в файл (просто так, чтобы посмотреть ее)
Когда я просматриваю этот файл в редакторе Notepad++, то там выводится вот такая строка
[image]

Как видите сначала идут непонятные символы, а потом "просвечивается" текст. Как раз тот текст мне и нужно отсортировать (там его еще много). Но мне мешают эти все символы, я не знаю как их удалить, когда я в C# читаю строку (метод ReadLine()) то если она начинается с такого символа "NUL" как на рисунке, то в текст она его вообще не переделывает.

Помогите пожалуйста с решением этого вопроса. Если кто знает как можно нормально записать этот текст в переменную/файл пожалуйста напишите. Очень нужно
Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читай байты из входного стрима, и если байт в диапазоне текстовых значений - писать его в выходной стрим.

что то типа такого:

```
    var readStream = new FileStream("FileName", FileMode.Open);
    var writeStream = new FileStream("OutFileName", FileMode.Create);
    while(readStream.CanRead)
    {
        var b = readStream.ReadByte();
        if((b >= ' ' && b <= 'z') || (b >='А' && b <='я'))
        {
            writeStream.WriteByte((byte) b);
        }
    }
    readStream.Close();
    writeStream.Close();
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста написать маленький фрагмент этого кода? Хотя бы просто пример.

Comment: Хороший способ!

Comment: В качестве учебного примера - да :-)

Comment: Не очень понял, что конкретно нужно было автору вопроса, но вы, например, пропустили в вашем способе все `multibyte` текстовые символы. А еще имеет смысл пользоваться функциями `Char.IsLetter, Char.IsNumber` и т.п.

Comment: Да, абслютно с вами согласен, но в данном случае я решил не рвать юному хакеру голову и предоставить ему возможность дойти до этого самому. По мне вырывать текст таким образом из "хрен знает как скомпилированного exe файла" - уже подразумевает что дело всё правильно не хочеться и дойти до правильного и поять можно только собственным тернистым путём.

Comment: А ещё, если смотреть на вопрос автора, то видно что мульти байта в куске текста нету. Но вот насчёт Char.IsLetterm и Char.isNumber - это хорошо.